# Initialize for-loop within if-statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop

Is it possible to have the start of a for-loop within an if-statement. For example:

```
if condition true 

    for j=1:10 

else % condition false

    for j=11:20

end % End of if-statement

    % inner part of for-loop

end % End of for-loop
```

I know this is not the most beautiful approach, but in some cases it might be easier than simple coding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that doesn't work.

But you can do

```
if condition
    range=1:10
else % condition false
    range=11:20
end % End of if-statement

for j=range
    % inner part of for-loop
end % End of for-loop
```

Comment: Nice solution. If things are more complicated (e.g. you may need to use both ranges sequentially) you can also just put the loop in a function, and call the function with the proper range at different spots.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin This is right, but is essentially a special version of this solution when/where `range` is a parameter of this function.